How to escape backslash loads from dotenv json variable python
I have a dotenv variable saved into .env file (in json format).
Example:
my_env_variable = '{"ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
    "user": "my\user",
    "password": "password"}'    

Reading this variable form my .py script (connection is a enum type DBConnection)
from os import environ as env
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

class DatabaseUtils:
   @staticmethod
   def get_data_from_db(connection:DBConnection , script_path, query):
      selected_connection = json.loads(env[connection.value].replace('\n', ''))

      user = selected_connection["user"]

Unfortunately, I got an error message, due to backslash in user (coming from json) and gives error:
self = <json.decoder.JSONDecoder object at 0x000001295223F0D0>
s = '{"instance_ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",        "user": "my\user",        "password": "password"'
idx = 0

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 70 (char 69)

What is the best solution to escape the backslash? Unfortunately, I cannot omit like r'value' because the parameter is in the .env file and cannot add "r" before the json
Edit: I also try with json.dumps before json.loads, but in this case I cannot

selected_connection["user"]

anymore, because selection_connection became a str

The issue you're encountering is due to the backslash in the string "my\user". In JSON, a backslash is used as an escape character, and when it's part of a string, it needs to be properly escaped (i.e., you need to use \ instead of . my_env_variable = '{"ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx", "user": "my\\user", "password": "password"}'

@LucasM.Uriarte when changing the variable as you mentioned, still got the same error.
my_env_variable = '{"ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",     "user": "my\\user",     "password": "password"}' 
results
self = <json.decoder.JSONDecoder object at 0x000001295223F0D0> s = '{"instance_ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",        "user": "my\\user",        "password": "password"' idx = 0

If you json.dump your JSON string, you just get a JSON representation of a string. json.loading that again you just get the original value back: a string.

Backslashes needs to be escaped once for env file and once for JSON string, so two times:
my_env_variable = '{"ip": "xx.xx.xxx.xxx",
    "user": "my\\\\user",
    "password": "password"}'


Thank you gent! I couldn't find this anywhere

try using this
selected_connection = json.loads(connection_data.replace('\n', '').replace('\', '\\'))

.replace('', '\\'))
this may also work

this is not possible, due to error in pycharm
',' or ')' expected Statement expected, found Py:BACKSLASH

there is exrta ')' in replace('', '\\')),  you can remove extra ')'
for reference
json.loads(connection_data.replace('\n', '').replace('', '\\'))
